# Dynamically add rows and run the script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that's creating rows dynamically upon button click. This input box contains an auto suggest script. When , I am trying to perform an input on the the first box(the one that is default created) , the auto complete works fine. But, on performing the dynamic adding of the row, the script for that row doesn't work. How to invoke the auto complete script on the new ?

```
     <html>
      <body>
 <div id="addButtonDiv">
    <button id="add"  >Add New</button> 
</div>
 <table id="tableAdd">
    <head>
        <tr>
            <th >enter</th>
        </tr>
    </head>
    <body>
        <tr>
            <td>
               {!! Form::text('nameId', null,['class'=>'form-control auto', 'placeholder' => 'name']) !!}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </body>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
         $("#add").click(function() 
         { 
             $('#tableAdd tr:last').after('<tr><td>{!! Form::text('project_manager_name', null,['class'=>'form-control pmID', 'placeholder' => 'Project Manager']) !!}</td></tr>')
        });
    }); 
    $(".auto")
            .on("keydown", keyDownEventForProjectAndCompetencyLead)
            .autocomplete(
                    {
                        //function that autocompletes the input
                    });


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery sometimes has a little trouble identifying elements that have been programatically added to the DOM just by the original class / id.  Try using a different selector method to check against the modified page:

```
 $(document)
        .on("keydown", ".auto", keyDownEventForProjectAndCompetencyLead)
        .autocomplete( // etc )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector isn't applying to DOM elements added after the page is loaded.

Modify as above to listen on all element in document that match, or attach listener on each new element created:

```html
<html>
<body>
    <button id="add">add</button>
    <table id="cooltable">
        <tr>
            <td>cool table cell</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function autoPopulate(event){
            // some code
            event.currentTarget.value = "auto populated content";
        }

        let add_button = document.getElementById('add');
        add_button.addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
            let new_row = document.createElement('tr'); // create row
            let new_cell = document.createElement('td'); // create cell
            let new_input = document.createElement('input'); // create input
            new_input.type = 'text';
            new_input.value = "default content";
            new_input.addEventListener('keydown', (event)=>{ // attach listener
                autoPopulate(event);
            });
            new_cell.appendChild(new_input) // add input to cell
            new_row.appendChild(new_cell) // add cell to row
            document.getElementById('cooltable').appendChild(new_row); // add row to table
        })

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is you are adding callback on "keyDown" event which is not happening hence your script is not running

To fix this you should add eventlistener on jquery load()

Or you should using .bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved') to call function when new node are added or deleted.

```
<div id='myParentDiv'> </div>

<button>Click </button>





    $("button").click(function(){
    $("#myParentDiv").append("<div class='test'></div>");
});

$("#myParentDiv").bind("DOMNodeInserted",function(){
    alert("child is appended");
});
```

Here is working demo
https://jsfiddle.net/vickykumarui/28edcsmb/

Code for Table Example

```
 <div id="addButtonDiv">
    <button id="add"  >Add New</button> 
</div>
 <table id="tableAdd">
    <head>
        <tr id = "test1">
            <th >enter</th>
        </tr>
    </head>
    <body>
        <tr>
            <td>
              Test 1
            </td>
        </tr>
    </body>
</table>

var  numberOFRow = 1;
$("#add").click(function(){
numberOFRow++
    $('#tableAdd tr:last').after('<tr id = test'+numberOFRow +'><td> Test' + numberOFRow + '</td></tr>')
});

$("#tableAdd").bind("DOMNodeInserted",function(){
    alert("Row number"+ numberOFRow+ "created");
});
```

Working Demo for your table examplehttps://jsfiddle.net/vickykumarui/qpxL8k4c/